# How to send cmd variables to java main function using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java program that is supposed to take an file name from the cmd. My main function looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            solve(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The `args` is a file name that I send it to the function `solve`. I am using eclipse. I went to `Run` menu and then, `Run Configuration`, and I pasted the file path in the `Arguments` tab for both the `Program arguments` and the `Vm arguments`. When I run my program using eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\MyFolder\MyFile
```

Comment: Please remove it from VM parameters, then all will be fine

Comment: You just need program arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add it to the VM arguments. Only to the Program arguments. VM arguments are arguments passed... to the VM. Like memory options, system properties, etc.

Comment: If the file path contains any spaces, you have to enclose the parameter in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from VM arguments, program arguments belong to the argumennts box.

VM arguments are arguments to java itselv, e.g. set maximum heap memory to 128MBytes: -Xmx128m

java interprets plain vm arguments as the main class it should execute.